# Удаление элементов из коллекции по кругу

Tags: java

Есть коллекция. Как можно удалить из нее все элементы(i) по кругу, пока не останется один?

Comment: У List можно напрямую обращаться к позиции через метод get. Дальше сами!

Comment: один первый или последний?

Comment: не тот, не другой. Просто единственный элемент в коллекции. Т.е. col.size = 1

Comment: @ДимкаКруглов вы сами поняли, что написали???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, вы просто хотите удалить случайный элемент в коллекции.

В List:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
 //Заполняем коллекцию
list.add(...);
...
Random random = new Random();
 //Мы удаляем один обьект по случайному индексу от 0 до размера коллекции не включительно
list.remove(random.nextInt(list.size()));
```

В Set:

```
//Так как Set Не гарантирует последовательность
     Set set = new HashSet();
     //Итератор для обхода коллекции
     //Удаляем один объект если коллекция не пустая.
     if (iterator.hasNext()) set.remove(set.iterator().next());
```

Думаю этого пока что достаточно.
А чтобы сделать "по кругу" нужно завернуть строку удаления объекта в цикл:

```
//coll это ваша коллекция
 while (coll.size()>1){
 //Удаление 1 элемента
 }
```

P.S. с Set можно if не писать, так как в while уже стоит условие проверки размера коллекции.